# How do I connect my SockJS client to my Spring Boot websocket endpoint?

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, sockjs

First I want to tell you about a bunch of tutorials that don't work:

[Using WebSocket to build an interactive web application](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

[Getting Started with Spring WebSockets in Java](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/getting-started-with-spring-websockets/)

[Spring Boot WebSocket STOMP SockJS Example](https://www.javaguides.net/2019/06/spring-boot-websocket-stomp-sockjs-example.html)

[Intro to WebSockets with Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring)

These tutorials say things like:

`var socket = new SockJS('/chat');`

`var socket = new SockJS('/ws');`

`var socket = new SockJS('/gs-guide-websocket');`

`let sock = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/stomp");`

My impression is that, if there is no "localhost", then it's trying to connect on the same domain. Meaning the frontend in `/chat`, `/ws` etc are on `localhost:8080` and so is the backend server. But that doesn't work for me because my frontend is `localhost:5173` and my backend is `localhost:8080` so I have to tell it where to go. I confirm my suspicion because I get `GET http://localhost:5173/stomp/info?t=1680631128497 404` when I put `var socket = new SockJS('/stomp');`. So at least I know a bit of my code is right.

I don't know what my expected result is, because (1) I am new to websockets (2) I am new to Spring Boot and (3) I am new to SockJS. But I want one of my log statements to be triggered so I know the code was reached, or for a message sent from the backend to be logged on the client, or vice versa.

My actual result is that I get: `GET http://localhost:8080/stomp/info?t=1680630627152 404`

This failure message makes me think I need a `/stomp/info` endpoint. Yet none of the tutorials mention a `/info` endpoint. So I don't need one, or else they'd all say that.

Here is my frontend code:

```
  import Stomp from "stompjs";

            function connect() {
                var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/stomp');
                // the code fails around here
                stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);  
                stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                    setConnected(true);
                    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/messages', function(messageOutput) {
                        showMessageOutput(JSON.parse(messageOutput.body));
                    });
                });
            }

// later...
<svelte:head>
    <title>Chat WebSocket</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client@1/dist/sockjs.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="resources/js/stomp.js"></script> -->
</svelte:head>
```

Then in Spring Boot:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
   
      registry.addEndpoint("/stomp")
        .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:5173").withSockJS();
  }

}
```

The chat controller:

```
@Controller
public class ChatController {

    @MessageMapping("/cat")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessage hatResponse(@Payload final ChatMessage chat) {
        System.out.println("hat");
        return chat;
    }
}
```

Here's another bunch of ways to use SockJS that don't work:

`/app/chat`: `var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/app/cat');` gives `GET http://localhost:8080/app/cat/info?t=1680631745245 404`

`/app/stomp`: `var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/app/stomp');` gives `GET http://localhost:5173/stomp/info?t=1680631712894 404`

`/stomp`: `var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/stomp');` gives `GET http://localhost:5173/stomp/info?t=1680631676987 404`

`/cat`: `var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/cat');` gives `GET http://localhost:8080/cat/info?t=1680631770418 404`

none of the tutorials mention a /info endpoint. If the /info endpoint is a requirement, why don't the tutorials mention it? Four in a row establishes a strong pattern. So it obviously isn't this.

I don't know what to do. Java, Spring Boot, and Websockets are all new to me, so this is a lot to chew all at once.

Edit: more research

[Spring boot Websocket without SockJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67920378/spring-boot-websocket-without-sockjs) says:

"If someone wants to use SockJS client to connect, they can connect using...

```
var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/test');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
```

"

This means the problem must be elsewhere in my code, since the poster was doing it the way I do. But where to look for the problem?

edit apr 16 2023: Here are some research links I found

[Webpack dev server sockjs-node returns 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66556191/webpack-dev-server-sockjs-node-returns-404-error)

[sockjs info 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45138738/sockjs-info-404-error)

[sockjs-node/info? 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012885/sockjs-node-info-404-not-found)

I think these links don't help me with the spring boot side of the equation.

2nd edit apr 16 2023: here's a link that does help!

[Spring Websocket and 404 status on connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883033/spring-websocket-and-404-status-on-connection)